# Error while submit link on reddit with php curl

Tags: php, curl, reddit

I am trying to submit link Post on reddit.com using php curl. I am having  access token of user but i am unable to post on reddit and getting an error code 403. Here is sample code what I am trying to execute :

```
$subreddit='funny';
$kind='link';

$postVals = sprintf("kind=%s&sr=%s&title=%s&r=%s",
            $kind,
            $subreddit,
            urlencode('Test Post'),
            $subreddit);
$postVals .= "&url=" . urlencode( 'http://seextra.com');

$urlSubmit = "http://www.reddit.com/api/v1/submit";
$ch = curl_init($urlSubmit);
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10
);

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
    $options[CURLOPT_USERAGENT] =      $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
}

if ($postVals != null){
    $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $postVals;
    $options[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] = "POST";
}

$headers = array("Authorization:bearer".$access_token , "User-Agent:".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$options[CURLOPT_HEADER] = false;
$options[CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT] = false;
$options[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = $headers;
$options[CURLOPT_USERPWD] = Reddit_Client_Id . ":" . Reddit_Client_secret; 

// Reddit_Client_Id client id
// Reddit_Client_secret secret key
$options[CURLOPT_SSLVERSION] = 4;
$options[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
$options[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;
pr($options);

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$apiResponse = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($apiResponse);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($response);
```

Here is response from reddit :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [error] => 403
)
```

Could you help me out regarding this.

Thanks,
Sachin

Comment: Are you sure you have access to appropriate authority to resources and your access token is correct ?

Comment: Yes I do have  as i am getting access token and refresh token of the user  every time i am trying to connect reddit.com using CURL via  POST Method.
Here are the post fields i am using for authorization.

$fields = array("grant_type" => "authorization_code", "code" => $_GET["code"], "redirect_uri" => Reddit_redirect_uri);

and Here is what i am getting access token response:

stdClass Object
(
   [access_token] => /*access_token*/
    [token_type] => bearer
    [expires_in] => 3600
    [refresh_token] =>/* refresh token*/
    [scope] => identity submit
)